# How to adjust page size (not margins?) in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, margins

I am experiencing a bizarre quirk on Word, wherein my page's margins (or something else that I don't know the terminology for) have been adjusted without me being aware of how it happened (see picture below, the right margin):

[image]

Comment: It looks like the Comments pane, which would show up if you had inserted any comments. But it may show up for other reasons - I can't check right now, but it is probably worth checking whether you have any comments and go through the settings in the Review tab in the ribbon (for example, there is an option not to show comments)

Comment: The comments pane also appears if you have tracked formatting changes -- and the Review tab is the place to check for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are options to change Page, Paper Size and Page Orientation.

The Comments pane is a possible explanation for a sudden page modification.

***I'll leave my post as wiki for edits.***